# Extract root domain by a Google Sheets regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need a formula which can strip any sort of URL from the beginning until the root (no matter what structure the overall URL is) and everything after the root also needs to be stripped (including the trailing `/`).

Here are two formulas I found in other threads:

---

Formula 1:

```
=trim(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"https?://",""),"^(w{3}\.)?","")&"/","([^/?]+)"))
```

This strips everything from a root domain, except for sub domains.

---

Formula 2:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("."&A2&"/","\.([^.]+\.[^./?]+)(?:/|\?)")
```

This strips everything from a root domain, except `https://`.

---

**Edit:** I've been messing with it a bit more. Formula 2 can deal with `https://www.` and `http://www.` but not with `https:` or `http:`.

Here's a screenshot of formula examples in G sheets:
[image: formula]

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.

Is there a formula to compare a cell value in sheet 1 to the values of an entire row in a second sheet? Then, if the cell value from sheet 1 matches a value from sheet 2, there's a background color added to the original cell?

Comment: Question is off topic for this thread, so I made a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508390/google-sheets-compare-cell-value-in-sheet-1-to-cell-values-in-a-column-of-sheet

Answer (score 3):

There are many approaches, here is a fairly straightforward one:

```
=regexextract(regexreplace(regexreplace(A1, "^[^/]*//", ""), "/.*$", ""), "[^.]+\.[^.]+$")
```

Step by step:

1. Remove  `^[^/]*//`, this is the protocol part of the URL, including both slashes.
2. Remove `/.*$`, this is everything after the first slash, including that slash.
3. Extract `[^.]+\.[^.]+$` that is the last two groups of non-dot characters separated by a dot, e.g., `example.com`

Comment: Worked better than the answers given here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59397319/1580234 Thanks!