# Google sheets: Compare cell value in sheet 1 to cell values in a column of sheet 2

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a 2 worksheets within a single file. Col A in each sheet has a list of websites. When I enter a new website to col A of sheet 1, I need it to compare the entry to the list on sheet 2.

If the same website is listed on sheet 2, I need the new entry to be marked in some way - red background, bolded, whatever.

What it should look like:

Sheet 1:
https://i.gyazo.com/07667520bc0f58a1dd2547405545eb5e.png

Sheet 2:
https://i.gyazo.com/a524832a9cb96e35bd2981e95e5c1edf.png

Stackoverflow is listed on sheet 2, so when it's added to sheet 1 it's marked with red.

I've been Googling and checking SO threads for about an hour, but I can't even begin to figure this out. I have very little experience with this stuff.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible with Format>Conditional Formatting
then set a Rule for formatting, there are many options including cell value 'equal to'
It should work.