# Google Sheets Formula for Extracting Domain From Website?

Tags: regex, url, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

```
REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"(?m)http(?:s?):\/\/.*?([^\.\/]+?\.[^\.]+?)(?:\/|$)")
```

Trying to extract domain from website

The formula above has worked for me if the link is like this: https://walmart.com/careers

However, it doesn't work if it's already a domain (walmart.com) or if it's www.walmart.com/careers

Is there a more thorough formula that can allow for these edge cases?

Comment: Try with `\b(https?:\/{2})?(\w+(-\w+)*\.)+\w+(-\w+)*\S+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A8:A12, "https?://www.|https?://|www.", ), "/"),,1))
```

[image: 0]

[image]

---

### UPDATE 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A8:A14, "https?://www.|https?://|www.", ), "/"),,1), 
 "\.(.+\..+)"), INDEX(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A8:A14, "https?://www.|https?://|www.", ), "/"),,1)))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE 2:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:ftp:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)")))
```

[image]

Comment: this is great except it only works if there's a / after the .com, ( so if it's just walmart.com it's not working) anyway to account for that in the RegEx? i know it's \z or something for the end of the string but my regex knowledge is iffy, trying to figure it out

Comment: also it doesn't work if there's something before the domain ie, careers.walmart.com/

Comment: @pilat `=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)")))`